# IE's text opacity not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, opacity

```
#subNavGal {
    position:relative;
    width:180px;
    height:30px;
    top:-160px;
    left:285px;
    padding-top:20px;
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.2s;
    -moz-transition:all linear 0.2s;
    -o-transition:all linear 0.2s;
    opacity:0.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity = 0);
}
```

the filter:alpha that was supposed to set the text inside this div's opacity to 0 is not working on the text. any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use both `filter` and `-ms-filter` to get opacity work on all IE (5 and up) versions:

```
.opaque {
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; // first!
  filter: alpha(opacity=50); // second!
}
```

See [opacity](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) on PPK for details

It may also be related to layout of you element if previous CSS don't get it done try to use something like `zoom:1` to check if it's related to layout of you element.

Answer (score 1):

for ie you will add values between 0-100 for the other browsers between 0-1 for example:

```
[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=55);
}
```